# Get actual location from Android device (Not the last one)

Tags: java, android, locationmanager

I want to get the actual location from an Android device, I know there are functions that return the last location registered, I want to press a button on my app and know THAT current location, not the last one

This is a lil code snippet from my app

```
if(GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(MyActivity.this) == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
            //get location
            LocationManager manager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            if(manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
                LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
                locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
                locationRequest.setInterval(2000);
                locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 3000, 5, locationListener);
            }else{
                Intent gpsIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(gpsIntent);
            }

        }
```

This code means, that after 2 seconds and 5 meters I will get a location update on my listener below

```
 @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        if(locationObtained){
            return;
        }
        location = loc;
        locationObtained = true;
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

So, am I doing well my work? I'm testing the app and receiving no location updates

Comment: what function of the activity life cycle are you using the above code ?

Comment: I'm getting the LocationManager object from a OnClickListener implementation @android_Muncher

Comment: What I am trying to point to is that if the above Code is in your onResume() method then you might get your updates but if it is in onCreate() you won't get any updates after the app is created.

Comment: I am doing all of this on a Button click listener

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get location from GPS, it can take some time, because GPS module needs to find satellites. So you need to wait couple or few minutes while GPS module find satellites.
If WI-FI location provider available you can get location more quick.

Additional info about location providers you can find here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html

Since Android has

```
GPS_PROVIDER and NETWORK_PROVIDER
```

you can register to both and start fetch events from onLocationChanged(Location location) from two at the same time. So far so good. Now the question do we need two results or we should take the best. As I know GPS_PROVIDER results have better accuracy than NETWORK_PROVIDER.

UPDATED:

for example you have location listener:

```
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
       //here you get locations from both providers
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }
};
```

YOu need to do something like that:

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,locationListener);
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0,locationListener);
```

but before registering you need to check is these providers available on this device, like that:

```
boolean network_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
boolean gps_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

Comment: How do I register both providers? two Location Managers?

Comment: So, I should register the same listener to the LocationManager, I'm still getting no response from LocationListener

Comment: Did you try it with registered NETWORK_PROVIDER and active Wi-Fi connection?

Comment: Just did, was an annoying NullPointerException I was not catching :( thanks a lot, your answer is the accepted one!

Answer (score 0):

If you are inside a building it can be hard to get a GPS location. Try to combine `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER` with `LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER` if you want location inside buildings too.